# couldn't match expected type IO t

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads

Could You tell my why I have error 'Couldn't match expected type IO t against inferred type String' - see below to see bad line:

```
data RectangleType = Rectangle Int Int Int deriving(Show)

menuRectangles :: [RectangleType] -> IO [RectangleType]
menuRectangles rs = do
    putStrLn "Please choose option:"
    putStrLn "3 - Show all rectangles"
    putStrLn "4 - Quit"
    putStr "Number: "
    n <- getLine
    case n of
        "3"         ->  do { showRectangles rs; menuRectangles rs }  -- this line is wrong
        "4"         ->  do { putStrLn "Quitting"; return rs }
        otherwise   ->  do { putStrLn "The End"; return rs }

showRectangles :: [RectangleType] -> String
showRectangles x = showingRectangles x

showingRectangles [] = "Empty"
showingRectangles (x:xs) = do printRectangle x
                              showingRectangles xs

printRectangle :: RectangleType -> String
printRectangle (Rectangle id width height) = "id: " ++ show id ++ "width: " ++ show width ++ "height: " ++ show height ++ "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `showingRectangles` is a pure function returning a string. Why use a `do` notation here? Change it to `printRectangle x ++ showingRectangles xs`.
2. Since `showRectangles` is just a pure function, it won't print to the console. The "statement" `showRectangles rs` is therefore invalid. You need to `putStrLn` it.

   ```
   "3" -> do { putStrLn (showRectangles rs); menuRectangles rs }
   ```

(BTW with this simple fix, the `showingRectangles` will always show `Empty` in the last line. You need to add one more definition to the function to avoid this.)

Comment: the best thing would be to drop the entire showingRectangle function and let showRectangles = foldr (++) "" . map printRectangles

Comment: @Ingo: Or `concatMap printRectangles`.

Comment: thx KennyTM and thx for idea with one more definition to function :)

Comment: `mr question` wants "Empty" for [] though

Answer (score 1):

Take more out of IO so you can see what is happening in your do block:

```
  data RectangleType = Rectangle Int Int Int deriving (Show)

  menuRectangles :: [RectangleType] -> IO [RectangleType]
  menuRectangles rs = do
    putStr options
    n <- getLine
    case n of
        "3"        -> putStrLn (showRectangles rs) >> menuRectangles rs  
        "4"        -> putStrLn "Quitting"          >> return rs 
        otherwise  -> putStrLn "The End"           >> return rs 

  showRectangles :: [RectangleType] -> String
  showRectangles [] = "Empty"
  showRectangles xs = concat (map showRectangle xs)

  showRectangle :: RectangleType -> String
  showRectangle (Rectangle id width height) = 
              "id: "      ++ show id ++ 
              " width: "  ++ show width ++ 
              " height: " ++ show height ++ "\n"

  options ::  String
  options =   "Please choose option:\n" ++
              "3 - Show all rectangles\n" ++
              "4 - Quit\n" ++ 
              "Number "

  -- for testing:
  r n = Rectangle n n n
  rectangleList = map r [1..10]
  testlist = showRectangles rectangleList 
  testempty = showRectangles []
  testio = menuRectangles rectangleList
```